# remove headers,footers,quotes in dataframes that contain documents

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp

Trying to preprocess this dataset to use it in an algorithm for NLP.

I have two dataframes. One with train data and another with test data.

Each looks kind of like this:

```
df.head()

                        news                               genre
0   From: mathew <mathew@mantis.co.uk>\n Subject: ...   alt.atheism
1   From: mathew <mathew@mantis.co.uk>\n Subject: ...   alt.atheism
2   From: I3150101@dbstu1.rz.tu-bs.de (Benedikt Ro...   alt.atheism
```

each row in `news` is a document.

Example:

```
df.news[4]
```

> 'From: strom@Watson.Ibm.Com (Rob Strom)\n Subject: Re: [soc.motss, et
>   al.] "Princeton axes matching funds for Boy Scouts"\n Distribution:
>   usa\n Organization: IBM Research\n Lines: 15\n \n In article
>   , n4hy@harder.ccr-p.ida.org
>   (Bob McGwier) writes:\n \n |> [1] HOWEVER, I hate economic terrorism
>   and political correctness\n |> worse than I hate this policy.  \n \n
>   \n |> [2] A more effective approach is to stop donating\n |> to ANY
>   organizating that directly or indirectly supports gay rights issues\n
>   |> until they end the boycott on funding of scouts.  \n \n Can
>   somebody reconcile the apparent contradiction between [1] and [2]?\n
>   \n -- \n Rob Strom, strom@watson.ibm.com, (914) 784-7641\n IBM
>   Research, 30 Saw Mill River Road, P.O. Box 704, Yorktown Heights, NY 
>   10598\n'

How can I improve the documents to get better results?

When I was working with Bunch type of data it was easy as you could simply do during import of the dataset:

```
 remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes')
```

Can you tell me how to remove those in the case we have here?

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; your question is quite vague and unclear, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Plus, the question itself has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `scikit-learn` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (please edit & remove).

Comment: Could you create a new column for each part of the news column? (Subject, Distribution, Organization...) Then you drop column that you don't want, or your create a clean_news column with joining only part that you want.

Comment: @desertnaut Allow me to explain, this is a main part of nlp so people who know about ML and nlp will probably be familiar with the process.as far as being vague I will modify the title accordingly.Thanks

Comment: You can use regular expressions to target what you want to remove.
see for example this post: https://medium.com/@datamonsters/text-preprocessing-in-python-steps-tools-and-examples-bf025f872908

Comment: It is way too messy to make something that can be applied using a loop for thousands of texts